# Additional information tab not working anymore

Tags: attributes, configuration, frontend, additional-information

I had an additional information tab on our product view page which displayed Attributes set to be *'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end'*.

I deleted the attributes as they had been named incorrectly but when I created a new attribute with the same setting & in the correct attribute group it does not show in a additional information tab anymore.  The additional information tab  seems to be not working.

I've checked the store scope when I added content to the new attribute from the Manage Products > Edit Product admin page.  I'm not sure what I could be missing?

I've refreshed my cache & re-indexed too.

Here are my screen shots of the setting.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you add your attribute to the correct Attribute Sets. Category -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  There is an extension on the our Magento Instalation called amasty color swatches which has a script on the page which disables the additional info tab.

here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        var amConfAutoSelectAttribute = 1;
                        confData = new AmConfigurableData({"9":{"short_description":"<p>Lorem Ipsim<\/p>","description":"<p>More Lorem Ipsum<\/p>","not_is_in_stock":false,"attributes":"    <h2>Additional Information<\/h2>\n    <table class=\"data-table\" id=\"product-attribute-specs-table\">\n        <col width=\"25%\" \/>\n        <col \/>\n        <tbody>\n                    <tr>\n                <th class=\"label\">TEST ATTR<\/th>\n                <td class=\"data\"><p>More Lorem Ipsum.<\/p><\/td>\n            <\/tr>\n                <\/tbody>\n    <\/table>\n    <script type=\"text\/javascript\">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')<\/script>\n","name":"COnf Atr 1","price_html":"\n\n                        // code ommited for brevity
                        confData.textNotAvailable = "Choose previous option please...";
                        confData.mediaUrlMain = "http://dev.domain.local/amconf/media/index/id/13/";
                        confData.oneAttributeReload = "1";
                        confData.imageContainer = ".product-img-box";
                        confData.useSimplePrice = "1";
                </script>
```

I was unable to disable this setting from the extensions settings on the admin panel.  I had to comment out line 62 of

**app/code/local/Amasty/Conf/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php**

```
 //'attributes'        => Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes', 'product.attributes', array('template' => "catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml"))->setProduct($simple)->toHtml()
```

I don't think this is a good solution though as the extension is grabing this data to swap simple product attributes with the parent configurable product attributes on the product view page.  I think the whole issue arises as the module is not compatible with Magento 1.9 rwd theme which puts the additional information in a tab.

Answer (score 0):

First add one attribute in Backend Category->Attributes ->Manage Attributes.

[image]

Then in Frontend section Mark it Visible on Product View Page.

[image].

Add label to your attribute.

[image]

Add/Drag attribute to default attribute set in Category-> Attributes->Manage Attribute Set.

[image]

Then Add new product and you will see your newly added attribute.

[image]

Save your product and you should be able to see new attribute vale on PDP.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your attribute, did you add your attribute to the correct Attribute Sets.

In Admin goto

> Category -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets